# TYPO3 displayCond: How can i specify additional optional conditions of the same field?

Tags: typo3

Basically: In the Backend i want to make specific fields only visible when the BE user chooses a specific value from a drop down menu of another field. I know i have to do this via displayCond in the TCAs, but i'm only able to define ONE condition or rather one value of the specific field to be the condition, like in this line:

```
'displayCond' => 'FIELD:checktype:=:4',
```

Checktype is a field that uses records from a foreign table in a select drop down menu. The specific condition is the Uid of my specified record. BUT: how can i add other Uids from the same field as optional conditions?

For instance, i experimented with this:

```
'displayCond' => 'FIELD:checktype:=:4||11||10',
```

Of course it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try:

```
'displayCond' => array (
    'OR' => array (
         'FIELD:checktype:=:4',
         'FIELD:checktype:=:10',
         'FIELD:checktype:=:11'
     )
 ),
```